# Can we define auth scopes for SAML?

Tags: google-oauth, saml-2.0, google-authenticator

I know that you can [define scopes for Google OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes), but can you define scopes for Google SAML?

I have read Google SAML docs and also some standard information about Google SAML, but wasn't able to get any info on it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

SAML is a different protocol where an identity provider grants access to a service. Since the SAML protocol only supports identity information it doesn't support OAuth 2.0 scopes, but SAML applications can request additional scopes through a regular consent screen after the user accesses the service.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, OAuth is an authorization process where is mainly OAuth 2.0 is designed as an authorization protocol permitting a user to share access to specific resources with a service provider.

OAuth handles authorization, and SAML handles authentication.

On the other hand, SAML is typically used for SSO in government and enterprise applications (identity management) which does not require scopes because it is an authentication process.

Regardless, OAuth2 does not support SSO. And SAML tends to be specific to a user, while OAuth tends to be specific to an application.

Moreover, Google Cloud platform has the option to use [OpenID connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect) where Google's OAuth 2.0 APIs can be used for both authentication and authorization.